# Non-Lie Subgroups

Tags: lie-groups, gr.group-theory, smooth-manifolds, dg.differential-geometry

A result of Borel and Lichnerowicz states that the [holonomy group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holonomy) of a connection on a principal $G$-bundle is a Lie subgroup of $G$ (Cartan had earlier asserted this, but apparently without proof).
This restriction, that it be a *Lie* subgroup, allows for a lot of poorly-behaved subgroups, for example a line with irrational slope on a torus.  This subgroup comes from a perfectly fine immersion of the Lie group $\mathbb{R}$, but it's not closed in the induced topology of the torus.

As an example of something that's *not* a Lie subgroup, let $G= \mathbb{R}$, consider an uncountable set of $\mathbb{Q}$-independent points, none of which are rational, and consider the subgroup they generate.  If this were a Lie subgroup it would be the image of an uncountable discrete space (there can't be anything $1$-dimensional, since we left out the rationals), which wouldn't be second countable, hence not a manifold and not a Lie group.

This seems like a pretty contrived example, and I suspect there is more content to 'being a Lie subgroup' than having countably many components.  However, I can't seem to pin down something that would illustrate this.  Can anyone give me an example of a connected subgroup of a Lie group that is not a Lie subgroup?

Comment: @Sammy: I think it is an immersion, unless I've got my definitions wrong. The derivative is clearly injective on tangent spaces.

Comment: You're right, Kevin.  I deleted my comment.

Comment: Your question inspired this one: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/3289/potential-connected-non-lie-subgroup

Answer (score 5):

As Aaron and Eric have pointed out, Yamabe's theorem is the statement that an arcwise connected subgroup of a Lie group must be a Lie subgroup. There is also a classical theorem by Cartan and Chevalley, also proved in Hochschild's book, that a connected locally compact topological group admitting a continuous homomorphism into a Lie group which is injective in a neighborhood of the identity must be a Lie group. In particular, if $H$ is a subgroup of a 
Lie group $G$ and $H$ is connected and locally compact with respect to a topology containing the relative topology, then $H$ is a Lie group (note that Prop. 2.11 in the book by Helgason only addresses local compactness in the relative topology).

> I found a very interesting discussion by Shahla Ahdout and Sheldon Rothman in the 
>   [Australian Mathematical Society Web Site - the Gazette](http://www.austms.org.au/Publ/Gazette/1997/Apr97/subgroups.html) in which they exhibit an example of connected, locally connected subgroup of the additive group $\mathbf R^2$ which contains no arcs and is dense in $\mathbf R^2$, essentially quoting F. Burton Jones, [Connected and disconnected plane sets and the functional equation f(x) +f(y) =f(x+y), Bull. Amer. Math. Soc. 49 (1942), 115-120](http://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1942-48-02/S0002-9904-1942-07615-4/S0002-9904-1942-07615-4.pdf). Such a subgroup is not a Lie 
>   group, indicating how essential is the role of arcwise connectivity.

**Edit**: Regarding Robert's post, it is certainly important to point out the different 
existing definitions of Lie subgroups. To make myself clear, I am using the definition of 
Lie subgroup as in the book by Helgason, ch.2 (or Warner, ch. 3), namely, a Lie subgroup of a Lie group is an abstract subgroup which is an (immersed) submanifold and may have a topology finer than the relative topology. I think this definition is very common and has the advantage of yielding, for a given Lie group, a bijective correspondence between 
Lie subalgebras of its Lie algebra and its Lie subgroups.

Comment: The definition in Helgason: a Lie subgroup of $G$ is a submanifold $H$ which is a subgroup of $G$, and is a topological group. A submanifold means that $H$ is a manifold endowed with an immersion $H\mapsto G$. In this def, any subgroup of $G$ could be considered as a 0-dimensional Lie subgroup, and we need beware that a Lie subgroup is not only determined by its image in $G$, and might be non-connected even if its image in $G$ is connected. A (quite artificial) way to avoid these issues is to assume $H$ has at most countably many components, as Helgason does explicitly in several propositions.

Comment: Yes, I also implicitly assumed manifolds are Hausdorff and second countable. I don't think the second countability is so artificial, as otherwise, e.g. $\mathbf R^2$ would have a very strange $1$-dimensional manifold structure by decomposing into a noncountably many copies of $\mathbf R$. It is also known that for a Lie group 
second countability follows from having countably many components. 

Answer (score 4):

As it turns out, any connected subgroup of a Lie group must be a Lie subgroup.  See Sigurdur Helgason's [book](http://books.google.com/books?id=wd-sXTUGk98C&dq=helgason+differential+geometry+lie+groups&printsec=frontcover&source=bn&hl=en&ei=JVDqSuKbHYXQtAOZ6ZHsCA&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=4&ved=0CBcQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=&f=false) for more details.

Comment: I don't have the book, but it appears that the theorem is for _path_-connected subgroups: http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=38356.  See http://mathoverflow.net/questions/3289/potential-connected-non-lie-subgroup for a counterexample that is connected but not path-connected.

Comment: I see.  Thanks for making the distinction!

Comment: On a quick skim, all I see is Theorem 2.3 which says that a connected closed subgroup is a Lie subgroup and prop. 2.11, a locally compact subgroup is closed. To my mind, this theorem gives a negative answer to the question Harold may have meant to ask, namely: "Are there are topologically reasonable subgroups which are not Lie subgroups?".

Answer (score 4):

Apparently, there is no consensus in the literature on how to define a Lie subgroup of a Lie group. One should be careful not to mix different definitions. The result of Yamabe (1950) states that every arcwise connected subgroup of a real Lie group is Lie subgroup (in the sense of Yamabe). Bourbaki uses the notion of an integral subgroup (Lie Groups and Lie Algebras, Chapter III, §8, Exercise 4). Onishchik/Vinberg use the notion of a virtual Lie subgroup (Foundations of Lie theory in Lie groups and Lie algebras I, p. 39, Theorem 2.4). Note that Onishchik/Vinberg also use the (stronger) notion of a Lie subgroup and present a counterexample not fulfilling their definition on page 14. For more on the technical details one can refer to Bourbaki (Chapter III, §6 and §8) or Onishchik/Vinberg.